# Changing form serialize data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

after a JS form serialize i have this:

```
.....&xx=xxx&otherError=&input=SMS&message=sdfgs&......
```

How can i change **message** val before ajax call putting a textarea val?

Thanks in advance,

Steve

Comment: Set the `textarea.val()` as needed first, then call `serialize()` on the form...

Answer (score 1):

Using **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method update the string.

```js
var str = '.....&xx=xxx&otherError=&input=SMS&message=sdfgs&......';

str = str.replace(/&message=[^&]+/, '&message=newvalue');

console.log(str);
```

---

Or update the input field value before serializing.

```
$('[name="message"]').val('newvalue');
```